# What is the distribution of the conditional mean E(Y|X) in a multiple regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, inference

Suppose the model is 
$$
Y = b_0 + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + b_3D + b_4X_1D + e  \\
e \sim\mathcal N(0, \sigma^2)
$$
Where $D$ is a categorical variable. 
$$
E(Y|X_1, X_2, D=1) \sim\mathcal ??  \\
E(Y|X_1, X_2, D=0) \sim\mathcal ??
$$
I want the sampling distribution that incorporates the uncertainty in estimated of $b$ and also leverage in $X$, and I'm guessing something to do with how many observations are in the group $D$.

Comment: What is the distribution of e?

Comment: Nevertheless, some assumption or other is necessary to compute what you asked for.

Comment: If you want to incorporate uncertainty in estimated regression coefficients and leverage, you will probably end up with a scaled and shifted $t$ distribution rather than the normal.

Comment: Sounds like no one knows the answer? This seems like a pretty basic question to ask, is it not?  @StasK, what do you mean, "If you want to"?   You have to follow the assumptions, this isn't a matter of preferences.  The model has the standard uncertainty of a E(Y|X) as in the basic OLS model.  Anyway, Glen, what is the answer then?  Seems like no one knows?  Honestly this seems like a basic question unless I'm mistaken.  I can find the answer for OLS but not for Multiple regression.

Comment: This should be in any decent regression textbook. The OLS estimator is unbiased, so if e is normal, the sampling distributions of the means will be normal and centered on $0$. You only need the variance (which unfortunately I don't remember, & I don't have my reg text nearby). Based on my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33642/7290), I suspect you could subtract the estimated error variance from the RHS of the last equation.

Comment: This is not a prediction interval.  I am asking for the distribution of E[Y|X] not Y|X though.  Also, yes, you would think it would be in any textbook but I looked through several and could not find it.

Comment: Also, your answer gung is for simple OLS, for multiple regression with interaction I imagine there might be some extra terms in there.  Any advice on how to go about deriving it?  I guess it is the distribution of sums of t-distributions and a normal, right?  What is the distribution of such a RV?  Need convolutions?

Comment: I suspect nobody is yet sure what you are asking.  The notation suggests both the $X_i$ and $D$ are random variables but the model explicitly makes only $e$ random.  Please edit the question to clarify the meanings of your notation.

Comment: @robbieboy74 this isn't a prediction interval; it's a confidence interval.

Comment: @ssdecontrol, that's what I said...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A confusing thing is determining what is random in the expression $E(Y|X)$, but assuming that what you want is 
$$X\hat \beta,$$ then $\hat \beta$ is the only random part.
Now of course if we estimate $\hat \beta$ on data $y = Z \beta + \epsilon$, $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ then
$$
\begin{align*}
\hat \beta & =  (Z^T Z)^{-1}Z^T y\\
& = (Z^T Z)^{-1}Z^T (Z \beta + \epsilon) \\
& = \beta + (Z^T Z)^{-1}Z^T \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$
so if the variance $\sigma^2$ were known, you'd have that simply that
$$
\begin{align*}
X \hat \beta & =  X\beta + X (Z^T Z)^{-1}Z^T \epsilon\\
&= X \beta + v
\end{align*}
$$
where $v \sim N(0, \Lambda)$ for $\Lambda = \sigma^2 X^T (Z^T Z)^{-T}(Z^T Z) (Z^T Z)^{-1} X = \sigma^2 X^T(Z^T Z)^{-1}X $.  So if you knew the variance $\sigma^2$, then sampling distribution is Normal, with the mean that you expect, and a variance that depends on how much information was in the design for the value you are interested in extrapolating for.

But since you don't know $\sigma^2$, you will use the consistent estimator $\hat {s^2}  = \frac{1}{n-p}\sum (y - Z \hat \beta)^2$, which we know is scale chi-square with $n-p$ dof, and independent of $\hat \beta$.  In this case, 
$$
\frac{v}{\hat s^2} \sim \left(X^T(Z^T Z)^{-1}X \right) t_{n-p},
$$
where $t_{n-p}$ is a t-distribution with $n-p$ dof.

So finally, 
$$
 \frac{\sigma^2}{\hat{s^2}} X \hat \beta \sim X \beta + \sigma^2 \left(X^T(Z^T Z)^{-1}X \right) t_{n-p}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming correct specification,
$$E(Y|X_1, X_2, D=1) = b_0 + b_1X_1 + b_2X_2 + b_3 + b_4X_1 + E(e|X_1, X_2, D=1)$$

and under the benchmark assumption of strict exogeneity of regressors with respect to the error term,

$$E(Y\mid X_1, X_2, D=1) = (b_0 + b_3) +(b_1+b_4)X_1 + b_2X_2 $$

or more compactly, setting

$$\mathbf \gamma = (\gamma_0, \gamma_1, \gamma_2)',\;\; \gamma_0= b_0 + b_3,\;\;\gamma_1= b_1 + b_4,\;\;\gamma_2= b_2 $$

and

$$Z = (1, X_1, X_2)'$$

$$\Rightarrow E(Y\mid Z, D=1) = Z'\mathbf \gamma $$

and analogously for the other case. Viewed as a random variable, this conditional expectation is a linear combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$ and so in order to discuss its distribution, we have to know or make assumptions on the distribution and dependence structure of the $X$-regressors, something that in many cases, it is not done. Note that $D$ plays no role since it is used in the conditioning *fixed* to a specific value.

Assume now that we want to consider another random variable, the estimated by method of moments (here, **OLS**) conditional expectation based on a sample of size $n$ which is treated as fixed. Here the $D$ variable will play a role since it will be used for the estimation of the parameters of he vector $\beta$. Denote $W= (1, X_1, X_2, D, X_1D)'$ and $\mathbf W_n$ the corresponding sample regressor matrix.
We estimate the original model, we obtain $\hat \beta$ from which we obtain $\hat \gamma$. Then

$$\hat E_n(Y\mid W, D=1, \mathbf W_n) = W'|_{D=1}\hat \beta = Z'\gamma +W'|_{D=1}\left(\mathbf W_n'\mathbf W_n\right)^{-1}\mathbf W_n'\mathbf e_n$$

Compacting, 
$$\left(\mathbf W_n'\mathbf W_n\right)^{-1}\mathbf W_n'\mathbf e_n = \mathbf u_n $$

So we can write

$$\hat E_n(Y\mid W, D=1, \mathbf W_n) = E(Y\mid Z, D=1)+W'|_{D=1}\mathbf u_n$$

which looks like it may have an even more complicated distribution, since here we have also products of random variables.

It doesn't look like a basic question to me. But is this what the OP had in mind? In any case, the treatment here is consistent with the notation used in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\left(a, b \right)$ denote the column vector $\left[\matrix{a & b}\right]^T$.

Assume that there exists a $k$-dimensional vector of "true" parameter values $b$, and that the "true" data generating process is described by $y = xb + e$ for any $k$-dimensional row vector $x$, where $e \sim \mathcal{N}{\left( 0, \sigma^2 \right)}$.

Suppose we used OLS to estimate the model parameters with $n$ data points "stacked" to form $k \times n$ matrix $X = \left(\matrix{x^1, \dots, x^n }\right)$. Denote the corresponding parameter estimates with $\hat{b}$.

If we observe some $x$ and denote $\widehat{\mathbb{E}{\left( y\ |\ z \right)}} = \hat{y}$ then
$$
\mathbb{E}{\left( \hat{y} \right)} =
x \cdot \hat{b}\\
\mathbb{V}\left( \hat{y} \right) =
\sqrt{\sigma^2x^T(X^TX)^{-1}x}
$$

Then for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$, the interval
$$
\hat{y} \pm \left(F^t_{n-(k+1)}\right)^{-1}{\left(\frac{\alpha}{2}\right)}\sqrt{s^2x^T(X^TX)^{-1}x}
$$

contains the true $\mathbb{E}{(y\ |\ z)}$ with probability $1-a$, where $\left(F^t_{n-(k+1)}\right)^{-1}$ is the inverse CDF of the $t$ distribution with $n-(k+1)$ degrees of freedom.

This is laid out, with slightly different notation, in:

> Mendenhall, William and Terry Sincich. (2012). Appendix B: the mechanics of multiple regression analysis. In *A Second Course in Statistics: Regression Analysis*, seventh edition (pp. 742-744). Prentice Hall.

---

In your case
$$
x = \left[\matrix{1 & x_1 & x_2 & d & x_1d}\right] \\
b = \left(b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4\right) \\
\hat{y} = \mathbb{E}{\left( \hat{b_0} + \hat{b_1}x_1 + \hat{b_2}x_2 + \hat{b_3}d + \hat{b_4}x_1d \right)}
$$
but that all just plugs into the math above. So no, the interaction doesn't make a difference.