# Error in linear regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, probability, correlation, mathematical-statistics

Given two series $(x_1,...x_n)$ and $(y_1,...y_n)$, and assume that we know $x_{n+1}$.
Given the fact that the pearson correlation won't change in the next observation of $y_{n+1}$, can we bound the error of predicting $y_{n+1}$ in terms of pearson correlation of two series?

Comment: At the very least you would need extra assumptions, e.g. about the relationship between $x$ and $y$. For instance, without any assumptions, $y_{n+1}$ could be anything and hence the error can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Right. I edited my question

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, your question is not entirely clear. You say "Given the fact that the pearson correlation won't change in the next observation of $y_{n+1}$", but correlation do not apply to a single observation, it applies to some well-defined population (or model). But maybe you try to say that the model do not change, that still do not give information about *which* model you have in mind.

*If* what you have in mind is a standard linear model (which would be my guess), then you can find an answer here:  [Obtaining a formula for prediction limits in a linear model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9131/obtaining-a-formula-for-prediction-limits-in-a-linear-model)  which tells you how to calculate *prediction intervals* in linear regression. The same principles (but not formulas) can be used for other kinds of models. For the difference between *confidence intervals* and prediction intervals see [Difference between confidence intervals and prediction intervals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16493/difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-prediction-intervals) or [Linear regression prediction interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33433/linear-regression-prediction-interval)

Answer (score 0):

Correlation is not sufficient to describe the distribution of the datapoints. You would need the full distribution in order to make predictions about the distribution of $y_{n+1}$ given $x_{n+1}$.

[Anscombe's quartet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) is a good example of the different types of relationships that you can have while the correlation is the same. In all the four images below the correlation is the same 0.816

[image: Anscombe's quartet]