# What is the best way to extrapolate when working with a linear regression model?

Tags: r, regression, model, extrapolation

There's not much more to ask than what I've written in the title.

Some of the values I want to predict are outside of the range used to build the regression model.

Comment: Can you please define "best"? It would be "best" to collect further data and thereby extent the range of training data so that you don't need to extrapolate.

Comment: Sorry about that. The best computational method to extrapolate values that are outside of the given range.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `predict` function. Try:

```
set.seed(123)

x <- 1:10
y <- -2 + 3 * x + rnorm(10)
our_data <- data.frame(y = y, x = x)
our_model <- lm(y ~ x, data = our_data)

predict(our_model, newdata =  data.frame(x = 20))
```

Comment: I believe the OP's concern is not with *evaluation* of the values but with the *extrapolation* involved in some cases.

Comment: I was under the impression that the predict function should not be used outside of the range used to build the regression model.

Comment: @user3552144 There is no such limitation in the `predict.lm` method. The method even provides the option of returning the prediction interval mentioned by whuber. Study `help("predict.lm")`.

Answer (score 1):

Once your model and its parameters are fixed, there's only one way to do it: plug in the covariate values of the point you want to extrapolate at.

Comment: I would like to suggest that a good *statistical* answer would also provide information about how to assess the uncertainty in the extrapolation.  That would address the implicit concern associated with extrapolation.

Comment: @whuber Fair enough request, but I'm not familiar with model-validation methods for extrapolation, only for a population that the training data is representative of.

Comment: One aspect you could readily point to is the [formula for a prediction interval](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33433) (or the better-known formula for a confidence interval of the fit) and the fact that as the regressors move away from their centroid, either interval expands quadratically. That provides a quantitative way to assess *how much* extrapolation is occurring and what its effects are on the uncertainty in the prediction or fit.

Comment: It is 'A' method but it is not correct to say it is the 'only' method. Using 'predict' as described by Qaswed would have to be simpler, especially when the model involved multiple co-efficients.

Comment: @dra_red But this is exactly what `predict` does.

Comment: Yes, Kodiologist, that is why it makes sense to use 'predict'...or are you saying something else?

Comment: @dra_red That is what I'm saying.