# 95% limits of a normally distributed parameter

Tags: normal-distribution, small-sample, t-distribution, tolerance-interval

How do I find the 95% limits of the population distribution of a normally distributed parameter? I've taken the mean and SD from 10 different readings of the parameter. Will the 95% limits be mean +/-1.96SD as per the normal distribution; or mean +/-2.262SD as per the t distribution as it is a small sample?

Comment: You need to specify one more quantity: with how much confidence do you want to estimate these limits?  The result is called a [tag:tolerance-interval].

Comment: 95% confidence will be good; but I'm confused according to which distribution should I calculate the upper and lower limits 95% limits from the mean of the sample that I've taken?

Comment: Neither.  The computation is based on the Normal assumption but it does not directly involve either the Normal distribution or the Student t distribution: the limits are found in a different way.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26702 for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_{10}$ is a random sample from a normal distribution with unknown mean $\mu$ and unknown SD $\sigma.$

**CI for normal $\sigma$ with $\mu$ unknown.** Then the 'pivotal quantity' $Q = \frac{9\,S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(df = 9),$
where $S^2$ is the sample *variance.*
Thus
$$P(2.700 < Q < 19.023) = P\left(\frac{9\,S^2}{19.023} < \sigma^2 < 
\frac{9\,S^2}{2.700}\right) = 0.95,$$
where percentage points .025 and .975 of the chi-squared distribution can be
found from printed tables or using software (such as R below).

Thus a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ is of the form $\left(\frac{9\,S^2}{19.023},\; 
\frac{9\,S^2}{2.700}\right)$ and a 95% CI for $\sigma$ can be found by taking square roots of the endpoints of the CI for $\sigma^2.$

```
qchisq(c(.025, .975), 9)
[1]  2.700389 19.022768
```

**Numerical example.** For example, the R code below generates $n = 10$ observations from
$\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\, \sigma=20),$ for which the sample SD is $S = 24.51.$
A 95% CI for $\sigma$ is $(16.86,\, 44.75).$ In this example where $\sigma$ is known because we simulated the data, we can see that the CI includes the
true value $\sigma = 20.$

```
set.seed(1122);  n = 10;  mu = 100;  sig = 20
x = rnorm(n, mu, sig);  s = sd(x);  s
[1] 24.51219
CI = sqrt((n-1)*s^2/qchisq(c(.975,.025), n-1));  CI[1] 
[1] 16.86035 44.74971
```

**Distribution of $Q.$** The relationship $Q = \frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \mathsf{Chisq}(\text{df} = n-1)$
can be proved using moment generating functions or by a multi-dimensional
orthogonal transformation. The simulation below, illustrates this relationship for
the parameter values used in this Answer.

```
set.seed(1118);  m=10^5;  n = 10;  mu = 100; sig = 20
q = replicate(m, (n-1)*sd(rnorm(n, mu, sig))^2/sig^2)
mean(q); var(q)
[1] 9.000164  # aprx E(Q) = 9
[1] 17.9578   # aprx Var(Q) = 18

HDR = "Simulated Dist'n of Q with Density of CHISQ(9)"
hist(q, prob=T, br=30, col="skyblue2", xlab="Q", main=HDR)
curve(dchisq(x, n-1), 0, max(q), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: I can't quite grasp how this answers the question: I am missing the part that accounts for the uncertainty in $\mu.$  Where do you handle that?

Comment: @whuber. Good points. I composed this answer before I saw your comment about tolerance intervals. Initially, I thought OP was looking for CIs for both $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and didn't know how to do the latter. In retrospect, I think it may be best to take down this Answer to avoid confusion. Please do so, if you wish.

Comment: I suspect you might already be close to an answer, because tolerance limits are confidence limits for linear combinations of $\mu$ and $\sigma.$

Comment: Thanks. I will try to sharpen my understanding of tolerance intervals.